# Java Histogram Array

Tags: java

I have to write a method that takes an array of 30 random integers and returns a new histogram array. The histogram should contain 11 elements with the following contents:

element 0 -- number of elements in the array that are <= 0

1 -- number of elements in the array that are == 1

2 -- number of elements in the array that are == 2

...

9 -- number of elements in the array that are == 9

10 -- number of elements in the array that are >= 10

I'm not sure how to make a histogram using random numbers. I have a method for making a histogram, and a method for making random numbers, but I'm not sure how to combine them.

```
public static int[] arrayHist(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt (0, 100);
    }
    return a; 
}

public static void printHist() {
    int[] scores = new int[30];
    int[] counts = new int [100];
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        counts[i] = arrayHist (scores, i, i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: *The histogram should contain 11 elements*: then why do you initialize counts to `new int[100]`? Write an array of random elements on paper. Write a result array of 11 elements, all initialized to 0, on paper. Loop through the array on random elements, and think of what you need to do ateach iteration to change the result array. Then translate to code.

Comment: "*Method **takes***..." means that the method has a parameter.

Comment: You have not shown any evidence of knowing how to make a histogram, and your code won't compile much less work.

Comment: @SikkiNixx: You claimed to know how to produce a histogram; are you now claiming that was a lie?

Comment: @ScottHunter The code I have for the histogram is a sample from the textbook; it never showed me how to combine both random numbers and histograms.

Comment: A histogram of non-random numbers is created the same way as a histogram of random numbers. The fact that the numbers are random is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to calculate a histogram of any given positive integer according to your specification:

```
public static int[] histogram(int[] scores) {
    int[] counts = new int [11];
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        int hist = scores[i] / 10;
        if(hist == 0) {
            counts[scores[i]]++;
        } else {
            counts[10] ++;
        }
    }
    return counts;
}
```

You can pass your array of random numbers to this function. Print the results accordantly.

Basically you have to split your implementation into functions.

1. Create array of random integer
2. Calculate the histogram (see my method as example)
3. Print the histogramm

You mustn't mix this thinks up ;)